# auto complete dropdown with huge and dynamic json file

Tags: json, autocomplete, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

i am looking for a solution for an auto-complete dropdown box which needs to load entries from a huge json (json file is also being updated / generated every second.)

I tried "typeahead.js" but by default it caches the json file in browser and was not able to display new entries added to json file.

is there a solution for an auto-complete text box which can load entries from the server as fast as possible ?

please suggest.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways which are mentioned in the documentation for typeahead.js

You can make the TTL value = 1 for prefetch ( this did;t work for me )

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md

Or you can use clearPrefetchCache on click page load or click of a button .

```
category.clearPrefetchCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can take advantage of Bloodhound, the typeahead.js suggestion engine. It provides two options. Prefetch and Remote.

In Prefetch, data is fetched and processed on initialization. If the browser supports local storage, the processed data will be cached there to prevent additional network requests on subsequent page loads.

In Remote, it will fetch data from remote source when ever you need it. But remember, in order to prevent an obscene number of requests being made to the remote endpoint, requests are rate-limited.

I think you should user Remote option in your situation.

Reference : [Link](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote)

Comment: Yes i am using Prefetch already. Found another solution mentioned below.